# Is it allowed to create a custom field dynamically through managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, tooling-api

Is it allowed to create a custom field dynamically(Tooling API) through managed package?

Will it create any issue from the salesforce review perspective?

What will be the best way to give access to the fields created dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily create field using Metadata API or tooling API. In past, I have created fields dynamically using Metadata API.

```
CustomField field = new CustomField(); 
field.setType(FieldType.Text); 
field.setDescription(description); 
field.setLabel("answerid"); 
field.setFullName("answerid__c"); 
field.setLength(lenght);

customObject.setFields(new CustomField[] {field});
UpsertResult[] results = metadataConnection.upsertMetadata(new Metadata[]{ customObject });
```

To assign the permission you need to update the profile metadata.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>ObjectName__c.Field__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
</Profile>
```

You can find Metadata API wrapper [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/tree/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes)

Comment: @ Tushar Shrama, Thanks for your response.

I know that We can create a custom field using metadata API as well as tooling API.

But, I wanted to know the salesforce security aspect for creating dynamic fields through manage pacakge. Whether it is allowed or not?

Comment: Tooling API approach to create custom field dynamically :

        String objectapiname = 'Contact';//replace with your object name
        String fieldapiname = 'CustomFieldUsingToolingAPI';//replace with your field name
        String fieldlabel = 'CustomFieldUsingToolingAPI';//replace with your field label
        String fielddescription = 'CustomFieldUsingToolingAPI';//replace with your field label

Comment: HttpRequest requestinside = new HttpRequest();
        requestinside.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        requestinside.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        requestinside.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/');
        requestinside.setMethod('POST');
        String fieldDef = '{"Metadata" : ';

Comment: String metadef = '"type" : "Text","description" : "'+fielddescription+'", "inlineHelpText" : "","precision" : null,"label" : "'+fieldlabel+'","length" : 255,"required" : false';
        fieldDef += '{'+metadef+'},';
        fieldDef += '"FullName" : "'+objectapiname+'.'+fieldapiname+'__c"}';
        system.debug(fieldDef);
        requestinside.setBody(fieldDef);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(requestinside);
        System.debug(res.getBody());

Comment: @HK As I mentioned I done this in past for app exchange project. So you can also do this.